# Android Error getting when load Font from asset folder

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

I am loading CSS from Asset folder. It’s working fine except font loading. I am getting following error while leading font.

**"Failed to decode downloaded font: file:///android_asset/css/seriff.ttf"**

Here my code,

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'MyFont';
         src: url('seriff.ttf');
    }

body {
        font-family: 'MyFont';
        background-color: #FFBB00;
    }

content = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/style.css\"><body>" + "Testing something" + "</body></html>";
newsView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Other CSS property is working fine. Please help if anyone have idea to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding `format('truetype')` after  `src: url('seriff.ttf')`?

Answer (score 0):

use relative path to the font

```
src: url('../fonts/seriff.ttf');
```

and to the css

```
href=\"./css/style.css\"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your ttf font is not compatible with the Android WebView. To confirm this replace your `seriff.ttf` file with another ttf file and see if it is displayed correctly.

You can use a ttf converter to read in the font then write it back out it should fix the issue. A site such as [freefontconverter.com](http://freefontconverter.com) will help with this task.